# How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to remove a highly referenced table in a SQL Server database.  How can I get a list of all the foreign key constraints I will need to remove in order to drop the table?

(SQL answers preferable over clicking about in the GUI of the management studio.)

Comment: See [How to Script Out all The Foreign Keys of a Table](http://www.siusic.com/wphchen/how-to-script-out-all-the-foreign-keys-of-a-table-106.html) for help. *Update*: Link no longer available but the relevant SQL was copied as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786606/1640661) to a related question. You can also view dependencies through the GUI.

Answer (score 1426, accepted):

Not sure why no one suggested but I use `sp_fkeys` to query foreign keys for a given table:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

You can also specify the schema:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = 'TableName', @pktable_owner = 'dbo'
```

Without specifying the schema, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql) state the following:

> If pktable_owner is not specified, the default table visibility rules
>   of the underlying DBMS apply.
>
> In SQL Server, if the current user owns a table with the specified
>   name, that table's columns are returned. If pktable_owner is not
>   specified and the current user does not own a table with the specified
>   pktable_name, the procedure looks for a table with the specified
>   pktable_name owned by the database owner. If one exists, that table's
>   columns are returned.

Comment: This isn't working for me on a sql 2008 database for some reason.  sp_help shows the relations, but this command will not.

Comment: @tbone: I had the same issue, which was related to not fully specifying the parameters. Given table T, owned by O, in database D you need to execute

EXEC sp_fkeys \@pktable_name='T', \@pktable_owner='O', \@pktable_qualifier='D'

Try looking at the output of EXEC sp_tables \@table_name ='T' to figure out what the parameter values should be.

Comment: The reason why no one probably suggested using this is because you cannot select just one column from it's return resultset like you can in the other examples.  For instance, I need to get the keys into a temp table so I can drop the foreign keys based on their names.

Comment: @JustinRusso You can get around this by creating a table, store the result into the table, then select the specific columns. Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure) for an example :).

Comment: just noted that you need to put the 'Destination' table in TableName

Comment: Works fine in SSMS 2014. Thanks.

Comment: It has already been answered in above comments: but just for clarity - EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = N'Department' ,@pktable_owner = N'dbo';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/ms175090.aspx

Comment: I have used this many times, though this will only work if your table is in the DBO schema. When the table in question is in another scheme, I would resort to something more along the lines of the answer by @Gishu below.

Comment: Works fine in SSMS 2012

Comment: Please note there is a bug with this function. It may return wrong values for DELETE_RULE and possibly UPDATE_RULE. For details see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/337535/sp-fkeys-delete-rule-column-returns-1-no-action-for-set-null-cascade-action-should-be-2

Comment: Works fine with other schemas but omit the [ ] : EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = N'Addresses' ,@pktable_owner = N'CCU'

Comment: Interesting.  WHen I script out this object, it contains the following mysterious sql: "KEY_SEQ             = isnull(convert(smallint,k.constraint_column_id), sysconv(smallint,0))," - any idea what SYSCONV is?  Appears to be a system internal version of CONVERT.  However, I can't seem to call it.

Comment: worked in Azure SQL Server.Do not add brackets [] around table name.

Comment: EXEC sp_fkeys 'table_name', 'schema_name' , 'database_name'

Answer (score 315):

This gives you:

- The FK itself itself
- Schema that the FK belongs to
- The "*referencing table*" or the table that has the FK
- The "*referencing column*" or the column inside referencing table that points to the FK
- The "*referenced table*" or the table that has the key column that your FK is pointing to
- The "*referenced column*" or the column that is the key that your FK is pointing to

Code below:

```
SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS [table],
    col1.name AS [column],
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my oppinion if you want to filter the results afterwards.

Comment: Works great!  It'd be even better if you: a) prefix all Column Names with "Fk" / "Key"), b) suffix all Column Names with "Name", c) remove underscores, d) add KeyTableSchemaName, e) add default `order by`: KeyTableSchemaName,  KeyTableName, KeyColumnName, FkTableSchemaName, FkTableName, FkName, and f) change Column order to: KeyTableSchemaName, KeyTableName, KeyColumnName, FkTableSchemaName,  FkTableName, FkName, FkColumnName, a/b/c/d for consistency / most common Best Practice naming conventions and d/e for the most likely usage (listing FK dependents of a `Table`).

Comment: This query works best if you don't have any multi-column foreign keys.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not all FK scenarios are covered by the other answers

Comment: Great answer. @JirkaHanika you can extended it to work with multiple columns and listing their order https://stackoverflow.com/a/69972388

Comment: @cerved - Sure.  We could simply include fkc.constraint_column_id and the other schema in the SELECT list.  But those modifications could be seen as mildly off topic.  The OP would rather need a GROUP BY or a simpler query to eliminate those duplicate records for their own use case.

Comment: @JirkaHanika if you're just looking for foreign keys of a specific table, use `sp_fkeys`. There are situations where it's not a good fit

Comment: @CervEd - I'm not the OP.  I benefitted from this answer and from some others here repeatedly.

Comment: man! thats showing a lot! great job, thanks!

Answer (score 261):

I'd use the Database Diagramming feature in SQL Server Management Studio, but since you ruled that out - this worked for me in SQL Server 2008 (don't have 2005).

To get list of referring table and column names...

```
select 
    t.name as TableWithForeignKey, 
    fk.constraint_column_id as FK_PartNo, c.
    name as ForeignKeyColumn 
from 
    sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
inner join 
    sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
inner join 
    sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
where 
    fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id 
                               from sys.tables 
                               where name = 'TableOthersForeignKeyInto')
order by 
    TableWithForeignKey, FK_PartNo
```

To get names of foreign key constraints

```
select distinct name from sys.objects where object_id in 
(   select fk.constraint_object_id from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
    where fk.referenced_object_id = 
        (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'TableOthersForeignKeyInto')
)
```

Comment: great, though used referenced_object_id instead of parent.

select distinct name from sys.objects where object_id in 
(   select fk.constraint_object_id from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
    where fk.referenced_object_id = 
        (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'tablename')
)

Comment: You can get the name of FK by adding "object_name(constraint_object_id)" to the first query's select.

Comment: You can get object id object_id('TableOthersForeignKeyInto')

Comment: for me this is the best solution, very good. thank you!

Answer (score 183):

Try this :

```
sp_help 'TableName'
```

Comment: Nice helper method to know if you are exploring your db manually. Also, it works on Azure SQL Server .

Answer (score 51):

You should also mind the references to other objects.

If the table was highly referenced by other tables than it’s probably also highly referenced by other objects such as views, stored procedures, functions and more.

I’d really recommend GUI tool such as ‘view dependencies’ dialog in SSMS or free tool like [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) for this because searching for dependencies in other objects can be error prone if you want to do it only with SQL.

If SQL is the only option you could try doing it like this.

```
select O.name as [Object_Name], C.text as [Object_Definition]
from sys.syscomments C
inner join sys.all_objects O ON C.id = O.object_id
where C.text like '%table_name%'
```

Answer (score 24):

The original question asked to get a list of all foreign keys into a highly referenced table so that the table can be removed.

This little query returns all the 'drop foreign key' commands needed to drop all foreign keys into a particular table:

```
SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE ['+sch.name+'].['+referencingTable.Name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+foreignKey.name+']' '[DropCommand]'
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fk
    JOIN sys.tables referencingTable ON fk.parent_object_id = referencingTable.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sch ON referencingTable.schema_id = sch.schema_id
    JOIN sys.objects foreignKey ON foreignKey.object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
    JOIN sys.tables referencedTable ON fk.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id
WHERE referencedTable.name = 'MyTableName'
```

Example output:

```
[DropCommand]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OtherTable1] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_OtherTable1_MyTable]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OtherTable2] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_OtherTable2_MyTable]
```

Omit the WHERE-clause to get the drop commands for all foreign keys in the current database.

Comment: Can you add some explanation for what this is supposed to be doing / how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Does not work with Oracle

Answer (score 24):

Here's the SQL code I would use.

```
SELECT 
   f.name AS 'Name of Foreign Key',
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS 'Table name',
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) AS 'Fieldname',
   OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) AS 'References Table name',
   COL_NAME(t.object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) AS 'References fieldname',

   'ALTER TABLE [' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + ']  DROP CONSTRAINT [' + f.name + ']' AS 'Delete foreign key',

   'ALTER TABLE [' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + ']  WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [' + 
        f.name + '] FOREIGN KEY([' + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) + ']) REFERENCES ' + 
        '[' + OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) + '] ([' +
        COL_NAME(t.object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) + '])' AS 'Create foreign key'
    -- , delete_referential_action_desc AS 'UsesCascadeDelete'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f,
     sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc,
     sys.tables t 
WHERE f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
AND t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
AND OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) = 'Employees'      --  Just show the FKs which reference a particular table
ORDER BY 2
```

It's not particularly clear SQL, so let's look at an example.

So, supposing I wanted to drop the `Employees` table in Microsoft's beloved `Northwind` database, but SQL Server told me that one or more Foreign Keys were preventing me from doing this.

The SQL command above would return these results...

[image: Foreign Keyes]

It shows me that there are 3 Foreign Keys which reference the `Employees` table.  In other words, I wouldn't be allowed to delete (drop) this table until these three Foreign Keys are first deleted.

In the results, the first row is how the following Foreign Key constraint would be shown in the results.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([ReportsTo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeID])
```

The second-to-last column shows the SQL command I would need to use to *delete* one of these Foreign Keys, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE [Employees] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees]
```

...and the right-hand column shows the SQL to *create* it...

```
ALTER TABLE [Employees] WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees] 
FOREIGN KEY([ReportsTo]) REFERENCES [Employees] ([EmployeeID])
```

With all of these commands, you have everything you need to delete the relevant Foreign Keys to allow you to delete a table, then recreate them later.

Phew.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be clearer if you used inner join and on clauses instead of cross joins. But this was helpful non-the-less!

Comment: I extended the CreateForeignKey and added:
  ' + ON DELETE ' + (REPLACE(delete_referential_action_desc, '_', ' ') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) +
  ' ON UPDATE ' + (REPLACE(update_referential_action_desc, '_', ' ') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
  AS 'CreateForeignKeyScript'

Answer (score 24):

The most Simplest one is by using sys.foreign_keys_columns in SQL. Here the table contains the Object ids of all the foreign keys wrt their Referenced column ID Referenced Table ID as well as the Referencing Columns and Tables. As the Id's remains constant the result will be reliable for further modifications in Schema as well as tables.

Query:

```
SELECT    
OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.constraint_object_id) foreign_key_name
,OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) referencing_table_name
,COL_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id, fkeys.parent_column_id) referencing_column_name
,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) referencing_schema_name
,OBJECT_NAME (fkeys.referenced_object_id) referenced_table_name
,COL_NAME(fkeys.referenced_object_id, fkeys.referenced_column_id) 
referenced_column_name
,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeys.referenced_object_id) referenced_schema_name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkeys
```

We can also add filter by using 'where'

```
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) = 'table_name' AND 
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeys.parent_object_id) = 'schema_name'
```

Comment: This is excellent for when you need to remove whole DB constructs / sets of referenced tables.

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT PKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()),
       PKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O1.SCHEMA_ID)),
       PKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O1.NAME),
       PKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C1.NAME),
       FKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()),
       FKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O2.SCHEMA_ID)),
       FKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O2.NAME),
       FKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C2.NAME),
       -- Force the column to be non-nullable (see SQL BU 325751)
       --KEY_SEQ             = isnull(convert(smallint,k.constraint_column_id), sysconv(smallint,0)),
       UPDATE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.OBJECT_ID,'CnstIsUpdateCascade') 
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                      END),
       DELETE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.OBJECT_ID,'CnstIsDeleteCascade') 
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                      END),
       FK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,OBJECT_NAME(F.OBJECT_ID)),
       PK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,I.NAME),
       DEFERRABILITY = CONVERT(SMALLINT,7)   -- SQL_NOT_DEFERRABLE
FROM   SYS.ALL_OBJECTS O1,
       SYS.ALL_OBJECTS O2,
       SYS.ALL_COLUMNS C1,
       SYS.ALL_COLUMNS C2,
       SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS F
       INNER JOIN SYS.FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMNS K
         ON (K.CONSTRAINT_OBJECT_ID = F.OBJECT_ID)
       INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES I
         ON (F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
             AND F.KEY_INDEX_ID = I.INDEX_ID)
WHERE  O1.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
       AND O2.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
       AND C1.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
       AND C2.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
       AND C1.COLUMN_ID = K.REFERENCED_COLUMN_ID
       AND C2.COLUMN_ID = K.PARENT_COLUMN_ID
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT
  object_name(parent_object_id),
  object_name(referenced_object_id),
  name 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('Table Name')
```

Answer (score 15):

**List of all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server :**

You can get the referencing table name and column name through following query...

```
SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'TableName'
```

**And following screenshot for your understanding...**

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I am using this script to find all details related to foreign key. 
I am using INFORMATION.SCHEMA.
Below is a SQL Script:

```
SELECT 
    ccu.table_name AS SourceTable
    ,ccu.constraint_name AS SourceConstraint
    ,ccu.column_name AS SourceColumn
    ,kcu.table_name AS TargetTable
    ,kcu.column_name AS TargetColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
        ON ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu 
        ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME  
ORDER BY ccu.table_name
```

Comment: I haven't got a clue how this is supposed to be used. Please add explanation

Answer (score 8):

First

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'Table', 'Schema'
```

Then use [NimbleText](http://nimbletext.com/) to play with your results

Answer (score 6):

I know that its a late(very late) reply, but I find these easy ways to find all the `foreign_key_references`. Here're the solutions;

**Solution 01:**

```
EXEC SP_FKEYS 'MyTableName';   // It'll show you the all the information(in multiple tables) regarding to the TableName with all ForeignKey_References.
```

**Solution 02:**

```
EXEC SP_HELP 'MyTableName';   // It'll show all ForeignKey references in a single table.
```

**Solution 03:**

```
// It'll show you the Column_Name with Referenced_Table_Name

SELECT 
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) Column_Name,
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) Table_Name
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'MyTableName'
```

**Hopefully, this'll help you a lot. ;-)**

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) as ReferencingTable, 
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.constraint_object_id) as [FKContraint]
  FROM sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
 WHERE fk.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('ReferencedTable', 'U')
```

This only shows the relationship if the are foreign key constraints. My database apparently predates the FK constraint.Some table use triggers to enforce referential integrity, and sometimes there's nothing but a similarly named column to indicate the relationship (and no referential integrity at all).

Fortunately, we do have a consistent naming scene so I am able to find referencing tables 
and views like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) from sys.columns where name like 'client_id'
```

I used this select as the basis for generating a script the does what I need to do on
the related tables.

Answer (score 5):

Some good answers above. But I prefer to have the answer with *one* query.
This piece of code is taken from sys.sp_helpconstraint (sys proc)

That's the way Microsoft looks up if there are foreign keys associated to the tbl.

```
--setup variables. Just change 'Customer' to tbl you want
declare @objid int,
    @objname nvarchar(776)
select @objname = 'Customer'    
select @objid = object_id(@objname)

if exists (select * from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = @objid)
    select 'Table is referenced by foreign key' =
        db_name() + '.'
        + rtrim(schema_name(ObjectProperty(parent_object_id,'schemaid')))
        + '.' + object_name(parent_object_id)
        + ': ' + object_name(object_id)
    from sys.foreign_keys 
    where referenced_object_id = @objid 
    order by 1
```

The answer will look like this: test_db_name.dbo.Account: FK_Account_Customer

Comment: This is actually like 4 separate query statements... this does effectively the same thing in one statement: 


`select 
    db_name() + '.'
    + schema_name(ObjectProperty(parent_object_id,'schemaid')) + '.' 
    + object_name(parent_object_id) + ': ' 
    + object_name(object_id)
    AS "FK Reference"
from 
 sys.foreign_keys 
where 
 referenced_object_id = object_id('Customer')`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Parent table',
c.NAME 'Parent column name',
OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Referenced table',
cref.NAME 'Referenced column name'
FROM 
sys.foreign_key_columns fkc 
INNER JOIN 
sys.columns c 
   ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
      AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.columns cref 
   ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id 
      AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id  where   OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'tablename'
```

If you want to get the foreign key relation of all the tables exclude the `where` clause else write your tablename instead of `tablename`

Answer (score 5):

Most preferable answer by @BankZ

```
sp_help 'TableName'
```

additionally for different schema

```
sp_help 'schemaName.TableName'
```

Comment: Thanks. sp_help 'TableName' worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Mysql server has `information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table FYI, you can filter it by table name or referenced table name.

Comment: Does not work with Oracle

Answer (score 3):

Working off of what @Gishu did I was able to produce and use the following SQL in SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT t.name AS TableWithForeignKey, fk.constraint_column_id AS FK_PartNo, 
       c.name AS ForeignKeyColumn, o.name AS FK_Name 
  FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id 
                                  AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
       INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON fk.constraint_object_id = o.object_id
  WHERE fk.referenced_object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables 
                                        WHERE name = 'TableOthersForeignKeyInto')
  ORDER BY TableWithForeignKey, FK_PartNo;
```

Which Displays the tables, columns and Foreign Key names all in 1 query.

Answer (score 3):

**Determine primary keys and unique keys for all tables in a database...**

This should list all the constraints and at the end you can put your filters

```
/* CAST IS DONE , SO THAT OUTPUT INTEXT FILE REMAINS WITH SCREEN LIMIT*/
WITH   ALL_KEYS_IN_TABLE (CONSTRAINT_NAME,CONSTRAINT_TYPE,PARENT_TABLE_NAME,PARENT_COL_NAME,PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE,REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCE_COL_NAME) 
AS
(
SELECT  CONSTRAINT_NAME= CAST (PKnUKEY.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE=CAST (PKnUKEY.type_desc AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_TABLE_NAME=CAST (PKnUTable.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME=CAST ( PKnUKEYCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE=  oParentColDtl.DATA_TYPE,        
        REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME='' ,
        REFERENCE_COL_NAME='' 

FROM sys.key_constraints as PKnUKEY
    INNER JOIN sys.tables as PKnUTable
            ON PKnUTable.object_id = PKnUKEY.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns as PKnUColIdx
            ON PKnUColIdx.object_id = PKnUTable.object_id
            AND PKnUColIdx.index_id = PKnUKEY.unique_index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns as PKnUKEYCol
            ON PKnUKEYCol.object_id = PKnUTable.object_id
            AND PKnUKEYCol.column_id = PKnUColIdx.column_id
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oParentColDtl
            ON oParentColDtl.TABLE_NAME=PKnUTable.name
            AND oParentColDtl.COLUMN_NAME=PKnUKEYCol.name
UNION ALL
SELECT  CONSTRAINT_NAME= CAST (oConstraint.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FK',
        PARENT_TABLE_NAME=CAST (oParent.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME=CAST ( oParentCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE= oParentColDtl.DATA_TYPE,     
        REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME=CAST ( oReference.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        REFERENCE_COL_NAME=CAST (oReferenceCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) 
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oConstraint
            ON FKC.constraint_object_id=oConstraint.id 
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oParent
            ON FKC.parent_object_id=oParent.id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns oParentCol
            ON FKC.parent_object_id=oParentCol.object_id /* ID of the object to which this column belongs.*/
            AND FKC.parent_column_id=oParentCol.column_id/* ID of the column. Is unique within the object.Column IDs might not be sequential.*/
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oReference
            ON FKC.referenced_object_id=oReference.id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oParentColDtl
            ON oParentColDtl.TABLE_NAME=oParent.name
            AND oParentColDtl.COLUMN_NAME=oParentCol.name
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns oReferenceCol
            ON FKC.referenced_object_id=oReferenceCol.object_id /* ID of the object to which this column belongs.*/
            AND FKC.referenced_column_id=oReferenceCol.column_id/* ID of the column. Is unique within the object.Column IDs might not be sequential.*/

)

select * from   ALL_KEYS_IN_TABLE
where   
    PARENT_TABLE_NAME  in ('YOUR_TABLE_NAME') 
    or REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME  in ('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
ORDER BY PARENT_TABLE_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

For reference please read thru - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/09/16/469136.aspx

Comment: This contains too much information for the question asked. Could you include some explanation (and remove the extra code) to just answer the question, please? You posted this exact answer to two different questions, and each one only needs *part* of this answer.

Comment: I edited the answer - Determine primary keys and unique keys for all tables in a database... I think here the answer is appropriate , because the question is for all references.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this on 2008 and up.  It's similar to some other solutions listed but, the field names are proper cased to handle case specific (LatBin) collations.  Additionally, you can feed it a single table name and retrieve just the info for that table.

```
-->>SPECIFY THE DESIRED DB
USE ???
GO

/*********************************************************************************************

    LIST OUT ALL PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS IN A DB OR FOR A SPECIFIED TABLE

*********************************************************************************************/
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(255) 

/*******************/

    SET @tblName = NULL-->NULL will return all PK/FK constraints for every table in the database

/*******************/

SELECT PKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()), 
       PKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O1.schema_id)), 
       PKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O1.name), 
       PKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C1.name), 
       FKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()), 
       FKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O2.schema_id)), 
       FKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O2.name), 
       FKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C2.name), 
       -- Force the column to be non-nullable (see SQL BU 325751) 
       KEY_SEQ             = isnull(convert(smallint,K.constraint_column_id),0), 
       UPDATE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.object_id,'CnstIsUpdateCascade')  
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0 
                                        ELSE 1 
                                      END), 
       DELETE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.object_id,'CnstIsDeleteCascade')  
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0 
                                        ELSE 1 
                                      END), 
       FK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,OBJECT_NAME(F.object_id)), 
       PK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,I.name), 
       DEFERRABILITY = CONVERT(SMALLINT,7)   -- SQL_NOT_DEFERRABLE 
FROM   sys.all_objects O1, 
       sys.all_objects O2, 
       sys.all_columns C1, 
       sys.all_columns C2, 
       sys.foreign_keys F 
       INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns K 
         ON (K.constraint_object_id = F.object_id) 
       INNER JOIN sys.indexes I 
         ON (F.referenced_object_id = I.object_id 
             AND F.key_index_id = I.index_id) 
WHERE  O1.object_id = F.referenced_object_id 
       AND O2.object_id = F.parent_object_id 
       AND C1.object_id = F.referenced_object_id 
       AND C2.object_id = F.parent_object_id 
       AND C1.column_id = K.referenced_column_id
       AND C2.column_id = K.parent_column_id
       AND (   O1.name = @tblName 
            OR O2.name = @tblName
            OR @tblName IS null)
ORDER BY PKTABLE_NAME,FKTABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Also try.

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'tableName', 'schemaName'
```

with `sp_fkeys` you may filter the result by not only pk table name and schema but also with fk table name and schema. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best practice in my opinion to work over this scenario in SQL Server 2016.

You have to list the foreign keys using :

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

There you can see the full info of the FKs. Notice the columns **FKTABLE_NAME, FKCOLUMN_NAME, FK_NAME, UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE** is the info you need to remove foreign keys and implement them again after truncate.

You can organise a script as follows:

```
-- EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'

-- DROP CONSTRAINTS: I drop one, here drop every constraint you desire. 
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS FK_TableName_OtherTable
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT

-- TRUNCATE 
BEGIN TRANSACTION
TRUNCATE TABLE TableName
GO
COMMIT


-- RECREATE CONSTRAINTS: I recreate 1, here recreate every fk you desire
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_TableName_OtherTable FOREIGN KEY
    (
    Id_FK
    ) REFERENCES dbo.OtherTable
    (
    Id
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 
GO
COMMIT
```

** Values for UPDATE_RULE and DELETE_RULE can be seen in [documentation of sp_fkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):
[image: sp_fkeys documentation for UPDATE_RULE and DELETE_RULE values]

Answer (score 1):

This gets any foreign key that involves the chosen table.  *Assumes a _FIRSTABLENAME_SECONDTABLENAME format.

```
 declare @tablename as varchar(MAX)
 SET @tablename = 'yourtablename'
 SELECT name
 FROM YOURDATABASE.sys.objects
 WHERE type_desc = 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT' and (name LIKE '%_' + @tablename + 'empdb_%' or name LIKE '%_' + @tablename )
```

This is a more general form:

```
 SELECT name
 FROM YOURDATABASE_PROD.sys.objects
 WHERE type_desc = 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT' and name LIKE '%' + @tablename + '%' and
 name NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]' + @tablename + '%' and name NOT LIKE '%' + @tablename + '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is how to get count of all responsibilities for selected Id. Just change @dbTableName value, @dbRowId value and its type (if int you need to remove '' in line no 82 (..SET @SQL = ..)). Enjoy.

```
DECLARE @dbTableName varchar(max) = 'User'
DECLARE @dbRowId uniqueidentifier = '21d34ecd-c1fd-11e2-8545-002219a42e1c'

DECLARE @FK_ROWCOUNT int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @PKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname
DECLARE @PKTABLE_OWNER sysname
DECLARE @PKTABLE_NAME sysname
DECLARE @PKCOLUMN_NAME sysname
DECLARE @FKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname
DECLARE @FKTABLE_OWNER sysname
DECLARE @FKTABLE_NAME sysname
DECLARE @FKCOLUMN_NAME sysname
DECLARE @UPDATE_RULE smallint
DECLARE @DELETE_RULE smallint
DECLARE @FK_NAME sysname
DECLARE @PK_NAME sysname
DECLARE @DEFERRABILITY sysname

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp1;
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( 
    PKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname,
    PKTABLE_OWNER sysname,
    PKTABLE_NAME sysname,
    PKCOLUMN_NAME sysname,
    FKTABLE_QUALIFIER sysname,
    FKTABLE_OWNER sysname,
    FKTABLE_NAME sysname,
    FKCOLUMN_NAME sysname,
    UPDATE_RULE smallint,
    DELETE_RULE smallint,
    FK_NAME sysname,
    PK_NAME sysname,
    DEFERRABILITY sysname,
    FK_ROWCOUNT int
    );
DECLARE FK_Counter_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()),
       PKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O1.SCHEMA_ID)),
       PKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O1.NAME),
       PKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C1.NAME),
       FKTABLE_QUALIFIER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,DB_NAME()),
       FKTABLE_OWNER = CONVERT(SYSNAME,SCHEMA_NAME(O2.SCHEMA_ID)),
       FKTABLE_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,O2.NAME),
       FKCOLUMN_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,C2.NAME),
       -- Force the column to be non-nullable (see SQL BU 325751)
       --KEY_SEQ             = isnull(convert(smallint,k.constraint_column_id), sysconv(smallint,0)),
       UPDATE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.OBJECT_ID,'CnstIsUpdateCascade') 
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                      END),
       DELETE_RULE = CONVERT(SMALLINT,CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(F.OBJECT_ID,'CnstIsDeleteCascade') 
                                        WHEN 1 THEN 0
                                        ELSE 1
                                      END),
       FK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,OBJECT_NAME(F.OBJECT_ID)),
       PK_NAME = CONVERT(SYSNAME,I.NAME),
       DEFERRABILITY = CONVERT(SMALLINT,7)   -- SQL_NOT_DEFERRABLE
    FROM   SYS.ALL_OBJECTS O1,
           SYS.ALL_OBJECTS O2,
           SYS.ALL_COLUMNS C1,
           SYS.ALL_COLUMNS C2,
           SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS F
           INNER JOIN SYS.FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMNS K
             ON (K.CONSTRAINT_OBJECT_ID = F.OBJECT_ID)
           INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES I
             ON (F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = I.OBJECT_ID
                 AND F.KEY_INDEX_ID = I.INDEX_ID)
    WHERE  O1.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
           AND O2.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
           AND C1.OBJECT_ID = F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
           AND C2.OBJECT_ID = F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID
           AND C1.COLUMN_ID = K.REFERENCED_COLUMN_ID
           AND C2.COLUMN_ID = K.PARENT_COLUMN_ID
           AND O1.NAME = @dbTableName
OPEN FK_Counter_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM FK_Counter_Cursor INTO @PKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @PKTABLE_OWNER, @PKTABLE_NAME, @PKCOLUMN_NAME, @FKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @FKTABLE_OWNER, @FKTABLE_NAME, @FKCOLUMN_NAME, @UPDATE_RULE, @DELETE_RULE, @FK_NAME, @PK_NAME, @DEFERRABILITY;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT @dbCountOut = COUNT(*) FROM [' + @FKTABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + @FKCOLUMN_NAME + '] = ''' + CAST(@dbRowId AS varchar(max)) + '''';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dbCountOut int OUTPUT', @dbCountOut = @FK_ROWCOUNT OUTPUT;
        INSERT INTO #Temp1 (PKTABLE_QUALIFIER, PKTABLE_OWNER, PKTABLE_NAME, PKCOLUMN_NAME, FKTABLE_QUALIFIER, FKTABLE_OWNER, FKTABLE_NAME, FKCOLUMN_NAME, UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE, FK_NAME, PK_NAME, DEFERRABILITY, FK_ROWCOUNT) VALUES (@FKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @PKTABLE_OWNER, @PKTABLE_NAME, @PKCOLUMN_NAME, @FKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @FKTABLE_OWNER, @FKTABLE_NAME, @FKCOLUMN_NAME, @UPDATE_RULE, @DELETE_RULE, @FK_NAME, @PK_NAME, @DEFERRABILITY, @FK_ROWCOUNT)
      FETCH NEXT FROM FK_Counter_Cursor INTO @PKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @PKTABLE_OWNER, @PKTABLE_NAME, @PKCOLUMN_NAME, @FKTABLE_QUALIFIER, @FKTABLE_OWNER, @FKTABLE_NAME, @FKCOLUMN_NAME, @UPDATE_RULE, @DELETE_RULE, @FK_NAME, @PK_NAME, @DEFERRABILITY;
   END;
CLOSE FK_Counter_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE FK_Counter_Cursor;
GO
SELECT * FROM #Temp1
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution work for me:

```
--Eliminar las llaves foraneas
declare @query varchar(8000)
declare cursorRecorrerTabla cursor for

SELECT  'ALTER TABLE [PoaComFinH].['+sch.name+'].['+referencingTable.Name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+foreignKey.name+']' 'query'
FROM PoaComFinH.sys.foreign_key_columns fk
JOIN PoaComFinH.sys.tables referencingTable ON fk.parent_object_id = referencingTable.object_id
JOIN PoaComFinH.sys.schemas sch ON referencingTable.schema_id = sch.schema_id
JOIN PoaComFinH.sys.objects foreignKey ON foreignKey.object_id = fk.constraint_object_id
JOIN PoaComFinH.sys.tables referencedTable ON fk.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id


--3ro. abrir el cursor.
open cursorRecorrerTabla
fetch next from cursorRecorrerTabla
into @query
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
--inicio cuerpo del cursor
    print @query
    exec(@query)
--fin cuerpo del cursor
fetch next from cursorRecorrerTabla
into @query
end
--cerrar cursor
close cursorRecorrerTabla
deallocate cursorRecorrerTabla
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find through below query :

```
 SELECT OBJECT_NAME (FK.referenced_object_id) 'Referenced Table', 
      OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) 'Referring Table', FK.name 'Foreign Key', 
      COL_NAME(FK.referenced_object_id, FKC.referenced_column_id) 'Referenced Column',
      COL_NAME(FK.parent_object_id,FKC.parent_column_id) 'Referring Column'
     FROM sys.foreign_keys AS FK
             INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS FKC 
                 ON FKC.constraint_object_id = FK.OBJECT_ID
     WHERE OBJECT_NAME (FK.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableName'
     AND COL_NAME(FK.referenced_object_id, FKC.referenced_column_id) = 'YourColumnName'
     order by  OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with tab_list as (
    select t.name AS Table_Name, t.object_id, s.name AS Table_Schema  from sys.tables t, sys.schemas s 
     where t.schema_id = s.schema_id
       and s.name = 'your schema') 
select IIF(col.column_id = 1, tab.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + tab.TABLE_NAME, NULL) Table_Name,
       col.Name AS Column_Name, IIF(col.IS_NULLABLE= 0, 'NOT NULL', '') Nullable, st.name Type,
       CASE WHEN st.name = 'decimal' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), col.Precision) + ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), col.Scale) 
            WHEN col.max_length = -1 THEN 'max'
            WHEN st.name in ('int', 'bit', 'bigint', 'datetime2') THEN NULL
       ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), col.max_length / 2)
       END
       AS Length,
       ss.name + '.' + stab.name Referenced_Table, scol.name Referenced_Column 
from sys.COLUMNS col  
    INNER JOIN tab_list tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types st ON col.system_type_id = st.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = st.user_type_id 
    LEFT JOIN [sys].[foreign_key_columns] sfkc ON col.object_id = sfkc.parent_object_id AND col.column_id = sfkc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.tables stab ON sfkc.referenced_object_id = stab.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns scol ON sfkc.referenced_object_id = scol.object_id AND sfkc.referenced_column_id = scol.column_id 
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas ss ON ss.schema_id = stab.schema_id
```

Comment: This is a very big and juicy SQL. Could you explain on how it works so that we could be able to learn from it?

Comment: Thanks to @Simas JoneLiunas for editing my messy texts. I'm working on migration project and need to list up all the column's information including relationg(FK).
This script will show you the information on schema level. Modify a little more at the tab_list view for your specific purpose. It would be more simple if I knew the built-in functions on object id earlier :(.

Answer (score 1):

Personnally I use this :

```
declare @schema varchar(500) = 'the_schema';
declare @table varchar(500) = 'the_table';

SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch1.name + '.' + tab1.name + '.'+ col1.name AS [column1],
    sch2.name + '.'+ tab2.name + '.' + col2.name AS [column2],
    typ.name
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch1
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch1.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch2
    ON tab2.schema_id = sch2.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types typ ON col1.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
WHERE 
(tab1.name = @table and sch1.name = @schema)
OR (tab2.name = @table and sch2.name = @schema)
ORDER by col2.name
```

I like it because it's contained in one query (you can remove the `declare` and inline them in the query if you don't like them), and it doesn't rely on system procedures so it's highly customizable.

And it will give both :

- The foreign keys in my table
- The foreign keys referencing my table

Which I find convenient. I hope this will help other people reading this topic.

Answer (score -1):

This answer builds [on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929992) but is formatted like `sp_fkeys`, works on multiple columns and lists their order.

```sql
SELECT fk_obj.name    AS FK_NAME,
       pk_schema.name AS PKTABLE_OWNER,
       pk_table.name  AS PKTABLE_NAME,
       pk_column.name AS PKCOLUMN_NAME,
       fk_schema.name AS FKTABLE_OWNER,
       fk_table.name  AS FKTABLE_NAME,
       fk_column.name AS FKCOLUMN_NAME,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (
           PARTITION BY fk_obj.name, fk_schema.name
           ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id
           )          AS KEY_SEQ
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
         INNER JOIN sys.objects fk_obj
                    ON fk_obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables fk_table
                    ON fk_table.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas fk_schema
                    ON fk_table.schema_id = fk_schema.schema_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns fk_column
                    ON fk_column.column_id = parent_column_id
                        AND fk_column.object_id = fk_table.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables pk_table
                    ON pk_table.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas pk_schema
                    ON pk_table.schema_id = pk_schema.schema_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns pk_column
                    ON pk_column.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
                        AND pk_column.object_id = pk_table.object_id;
```

Answer (score -2):

**Oracle SQL**

```
select *
from
    all_constraints
where
    r_constraint_name in
    (select       constraint_name
    from
       all_constraints
    where
       table_name='PUT_THE_TABLE_NAME_HERE');
```

`all_constraints` is an intrinsic table name in Oracle DB.