# why can't i delete this SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, drop-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find foreign key dependencies in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server)

i am trying to delete a table in SQL server mgmt studio by rightclicking and clicking "DELETE".  I am getting this error:

Could not drop object 'dbo.Team' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

how can i find out what is referencing this table as nothing should be.  Why wouldn't SQL server mgmt studio help point you to what is referencing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer can help you:

[How to find foreign key dependencies in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server)