# Find all foreign keys inside a relational DB - no RDBMS specific

Tags: .net, sql, foreign-keys

Given different data sources I would like to find out all foreign keys inside the database. The DB can be anything from SQLite to SQL Server and Oracle. Is there a generic way to do it? May be an ORM might be helpful?

There are some fine scripts on SO, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server). But this is SQL Server specific and I want to research the generic nature of the problem.

Comment: Each RDBS has its own proprietary data dictionary, so no, there isn't a generic solution.

Comment: Most RDBMS implementations should support the information schema views that are used in the question/answer you cited.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA could be a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only hope you have to be RDBMS agnostic is to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, which should be supported by any reasonably ANSI-SQL-compatible database system.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907879/sql-server-howto-get-foreign-key-reference-from-information-schema) on how to find the referential integrity constraints using `INFORMAITON_SCHEMA`. Queries like that *should* work on <strike>Oracle,</strike> MySQL and PostgreSQL etc. - but most likely *not* in SQLite (not ANSI compatible enough, as far as I can remember)

Comment: Oracle does not support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: **boo**, Oracle! That unfortunately just shows how little value those ANSI SQL standards really have in real life ... :-(