# Find all tables having foreign key given

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have a table A that has primary key Id. I want to find all tables that contain this key as foreign. Number of tables is about 100, so its rather impossible to use generated database diagram. Is it any way to to query database schema objects to find it? Or maybe some other ways?

Comment: And you're sure that all of those 100 tables actually relate to `TableA`?

Comment: sybase, oracle, sql server, etc.?

Comment: I would do this: Auto-Generate DB-Create-Skript. Search DB-Script for the ref-foreign-key-to-your-column syntax.

Comment: No of course, the reason i asked is that i'm not sure which tables relate to it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find foreign key dependencies in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server)

Comment: The schema does not provide cascade-deletion and in some cases I want to reassign all related objects to another instance of A by hands without errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about Sql Server Right Click on that table then `View Dependecies`

More info at :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630261.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_ID('dbo.TableA')
```

This finds all foreign keys that reference your `TableA`