# SQL Server : relationship between columns in different tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to find a way to understand if there is a relationship between two columns present in two different tables.

For example in the table `[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]`, I have a column `SalesOrderID` and in another table `[Person].[EmailAddress]`, there is `BusinessEntityID`.

How can I check to see if there is a table that creates a relationship between these 2 columns? Or how can I be sure that there is not a relationship between these 2 columns?

Comment: Have you tried `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`?

Comment: Are you using any software to view tables? Some software like MS Access allow you to see relationships.

Comment: Can you be sure that the designer of the database actually added foreign key constraints? Is there no design information regarding this database available?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find foreign key dependencies in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is what you are looking for. You can see whether or not a given column is used in a constraint by executing

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Person' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'BusinessEntityID'
```

You will have to do some additional work to focus on your specific solution, but this is where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one the following to find the tables that reference [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys @pktable_name = N'SalesOrderHeader',@pktable_owner = N'Sales';
```

Answer (score -1):

I apologize before hand for what follows:

```
    create table #rels (rel_name varchar(max), matches int) declare @sql varchar(max) = '' select @sql+= char(10) + 'insert into #rels select ''' tbla + '.'  + col_a + '.' + tbl_b + '.' col_b ''' colrel, count(*) from ' + tbl_a + ' join ' + tbl_b + '  on cast(' + col_a + ' as varchar(max)) = cast(' + col_b + ' as varchar(max)) from ( select a.column_name col_a, object_name(a.object_id) tbl_a, b.column_name col_b, object_name(b.object_id) tbl_b from sys.columns a cross apply sys.columns b where  a.column_name <> b.column_name where a.system_type_id = b.system_type_id ) cols exec (@sql) select * from #rels where matches > 0 order by matches desc drop table #rels
```

Comment: Some explanation of this code and the occasional CR would help a lot here.