# Creating non-clustered indexes with ServiceStack OrmLite on SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, ormlite-servicestack

I'm evaluating the use of ServiceStack's OrmLite in one of my current projects, and I require some control over the indexes that are created; I'd prefer to control as much of this via the data annotations where possible.

Unfortunately I'm having no luck forcing indexes over non-sequential IDs to be non-clustered. Using the following table model:

```
[Alias("Players")]
public class Player
{
    [Index(Unique = true, NonClustered = true)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

the `CreateTableIfNotExists<Player>()` method seems to ignore the indication to create a non-clustered index, and created a clustered one instead (which will result in [index fragmentation and poor performance](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/)):

[image]

What am I missing here?

Note: this is with OrmLite 4.0.52, using the `SqlServer2012Dialect` provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-standard RDBMS feature (i.e. not supported by most RDBMS's) that you'll have to manage outside of OrmLite, e.g: manually [dropping the clustered index on the Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604471/85785) then adding the clustered index.

You may also be able to leverage the [Post Custom SQL Hooks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pre--post-custom-sql-hooks-when-creating-and-dropping-tables) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Since those attribute parameters do nothing/silently faile, why do they exist at all?

Comment: @easuter The `[Index]` attribute is only used for creating Indexes on other non-Primary Key properties. The `[PrimaryKey]` and `[AutoIncrement]` attributes can be used on Primary Keys.

Comment: I understand this, however I wasn't inquiring about creation of primary keys, I was asking why the `[Index]` attribute's `NonClustered` parameter simply fails silently, instead of for example raising a `NotImplementedException`. Why do the `NonClustered` and `Clustered` parameters exist if they don't have any purpose?

Comment: @easuter The `[Index]` attribute is ignored for PK and [does get applied when creating indexes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/a55376f3d64327b90121e8b57be827a9e3a03a79/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L1136) for non-Primary Key properties.

Comment: I see, it's using the `Id` field as the primary key although I didn't explicitly specify this with `[PrimaryKey]`.

Answer (score 1):

This might alleviate your need for a non-clustered index.

I used a Converter to get sequential Guid's SQL Server likes in its clustered indexes for new insert.

```
public class SequentialSqlServerGuidConverter : SqlServerGuidConverter 
{
    public override object ToDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
    {  
        if (value is Guid && value.Equals(Guid.Empty))
        {
            var newGuid = SequentialGuidGenerator.NewSequentialGuid(SequentialGuidType.SequentialAtEnd);
            return newGuid;
        }
        return base.ToDbValue(fieldType, value);
    }
}
```

The `SequentialGuidGenerator` code can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database

It obviously has the side effect of changing all values of Guid.Empty to a new SequentialGuid. In practice, we are not trying to find rows which equal Guid.Empty so it isn't an issue.

Comment: thanks, that's an interesting solution that I'll keep in mind to test for future projects!