# Retrieve table relationships from MS Access DB using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, relationship

I am using C# with MS Access 2010. I need to retrieve the table relationships from the DB in order to determine the relationships between entities and use them in my C# code.
I need the same functionality for SQL Server database also.

Is there a way to do this using C# and .NET 3.0/ 3.5/ 4.0?

Appreciate your time.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I used to retrieve the foreign key constraints (the relationships, if you prefer). `TableSchema`, `ForeignKey` and `ForeignKeyColumn` are my own classes, where I store the result. The point is to use the `GetOleDbSchemaTable` method of the `OleDbConnection`:

```
private static void RetrieveForeignKeyInfo(OleDbConnection cnn, TableSchema tableSchema, Func<string, string> prepareColumnNameForMapping)
{
    string[] fkRestrictions = new string[] { null, null, null, null, null, tableSchema.TableName };
    using (DataTable dtForeignKeys = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, fkRestrictions)) {
        ForeignKey foreignKey = null;
        string constraintName = "";
        foreach (DataRow row in dtForeignKeys.Rows) {
            string newConstraintName = (string)row["FK_NAME"];
            if (newConstraintName != constraintName) {
                constraintName = newConstraintName;
                foreignKey = new ForeignKey();
                foreignKey.MasterTableName = (string)row["PK_TABLE_NAME"];
                tableSchema.ForeignKeys.Add(foreignKey);
            }
            var foreignKeyColumn = new ForeignKeyColumn();
            foreignKeyColumn.DetailColumnName = (string)row["FK_COLUMN_NAME"];
            foreignKeyColumn.MasterColumnName = (string)row["PK_COLUMN_NAME"];
            foreignKeyColumn.DetailColumnNameForMapping = prepareColumnNameForMapping(foreignKeyColumn.DetailColumnName);
            foreignKeyColumn.MasterColumnNameForMapping = prepareColumnNameForMapping(foreignKeyColumn.MasterColumnName);
            foreignKey.Columns.Add(foreignKeyColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to store the result of some SQL Query in the TableSchema class? If so, I do not have a specific chunk of data for which I need the foreign key relationships. I need to retrieve all the foreign key relationships present in the DB Schema.

Comment: My example retrieves the foreign keys for one table. The table name is specified in fkRestrictions. You don't have a TableSchema class. TableSchema and ForeignKey are classes that I have made for my purpose. You will get a DataTable from the cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable() call. You can try to pass null for the table name, or you can use a schema table that returns all the tables available. Have a look a the OleDbSchemaGuid class. There are a lot of schema tables available, each of them returning valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

I would use DAO, in which case the relationships are in a collection that you can retrieve from the `Relationships` property of the `Database` object.

In ADO.NET, you use the `Relations` property of the `DataSet` class.

Comment: I used DAO for Access DB. But what do I do for SQL Server DB? DataSet.Relations will not help, because I want all the foreign key relationships. I do not have a specific DataSet for which I need to find out the relationships.

Comment: Can't you get a SqlDataAdapter and call FillSchema to get the schema in the DataSet?

Comment: Again, I need a query for the SqlDataAdapter. There are nearly 80 tables in my DB for which I need to retrieve foreign key relationships without actual data.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005/483266