# A SQL script to identify all the FKs referencing a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, information-schema

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005)

I'm trying to use Information_Schema to find all the FKs referencing a particular table.  However I can only find the FKs that table holds onto others in the Constraint_Column_Usage and Constraint_Table_Usage tables.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks - that looks like exactly what I'm looking for - I've voted to close as dup