# Find all foreign key references to a certain table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that I would like to find all the other tables that foreign key it. I thought this thread had the answer: [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005)

But after trying those things, it doesn't actually list all the tables.

Comment: Have you tried simply `sp_help yourtablename`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't list all the tables that foreign key to this one.

Comment: Already answered here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: I posted that exact link in my question and said it didn't work for me.

Comment: `Yes. It doesn't list all the tables that foreign key to this one` Can you triple check?

Comment: It does not. That query listed 8 tables. The one below lists 12 tables. Basically if the other table's foreign key is also it's primary key, it doesn't include that in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
;WITH ReferencingFK AS 
(
    SELECT 
        fk.Name AS 'FKName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) 'ParentTable',
        cpa.name 'ParentColumnName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) 'ReferencedTable',
        cref.name 'ReferencedColumnName'
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cpa ON fkc.parent_object_id = cpa.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = cpa.column_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cref ON fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id
)
SELECT 
    FKName,
    ParentTable,
    ParentColumnName,
    ReferencedTable,
    ReferencedColumnName
FROM 
    ReferencingFK
WHERE
    ReferencedTable = '**YourTableNameHere**'
ORDER BY 
    ParentTable, ReferencedTable, FKName
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Wonder why sp_help doesn't list them all.

Answer (score 6):

Here you have another code snippet, at the end on the `WHERE` clause, substitute with your table name.

```
SELECT
    K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
    FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
    PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
    Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                i1.TABLE_NAME,
                i2.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE
                i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```