# How can I find foreign keys in cross databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 different database and I'm writing some stored procedures.
Is it possible to find foreign keys in cross databases with db names?

For ex:

> ForeignKey -- Table name -- Column name -- Reference table name --
>   Reference column name -- Reference Database name

Comment: Foreign key across DB or table? You can't define foreign key across DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FK relationships can't and don't exist across database boundaries. Obviously you may have related data in separate databases, but there's no tool/method to find them other than manual search.

Answer (score 0):

To get all foreign keys,

```
select t.name as TableWithForeignKey, fk.constraint_column_id as FK_PartNo , c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
    from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
    inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    where fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'TableOthersForeignKeyInto')
    order by TableWithForeignKey, FK_PartNo
```

Here you just need to change db names. 
Reference : [get foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: yeah as @Brian said, we cant have FK relationships between databases and with my reference you can just see foreign keys in dbs.