# Find all the related tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a database with around 1000 tables and I need to find all tables that relate to a specific one, let's say the customer table. How do I proceed?

Comment: Information schema views are helpfull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you ask to find all tables that relate to a specific one, I assume you are asking for all tables that have a foreign key reference to your "customer" table.  This is closely related to a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005).  The following query that uses the system catalog views should do the trick:

```
select t.name as TableWithForeignKey, fk.constraint_column_id as FK_columns , c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
    from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
        inner join sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        inner join sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    where fk.referenced_object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'customers')
    order by TableWithForeignKey, ForeignKeyColumn
```

[MSDN sys.foreign_key_columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186306.aspx)

Comment: Apparently my database didn't contain any foreign keys so I had to use like 'name%'. Your code worked when I tried with another database so thanks for your help :)