# How can I find out what FOREIGN KEY constraint references a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to drop a table but getting the following message:

> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Could not drop object 'dbo.UserProfile' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
>   Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   There is already an object named 'UserProfile' in the database.

I looked around with SQL Server Management Studio but I am unable to find the constraint. How can I find out the foreign key constraints?

Comment: I like sp_help 'dbo.TableName'

See here for more ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: `Worth noticing:` Answer by @LittleSweetSeas will return info about the foreign keys **FOR** a given **referenced table**, however @Gayathri-Varma 's answer details for a given **parent table**. Both are useful in different context and both win their own race :-)

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Here it is:

```
SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableName'
```

This way, you'll get the referencing table and column name.

Edited to use sys.tables instead of generic sys.objects as per comment suggestion.
Thanks, marc_s

Comment: You should use the more focused `sys.tables` rather than `sys.objects`

Comment: @marc_s: Thank u, but could you post an example? AFAIK in sys.tables i have no FK references

Comment: What I meant it: just replace `INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id` with `INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id`

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas i had run the above query still i am not getting the object_name and column name for the table which had a foreign key constraint

Comment: You could beef up your select with a little more info:  SELECT f.name ConstraintName, f.type_desc ConstraintType, OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) ConstrainedTable, COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) ConstrainedColumn, OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) ReferencedTable, COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) ReferencedColumn

Comment: Joined table `t` is never referenced, and this works for me without the second `inner join`. Is it superfluous? Has a recent change made its use moot?

Comment: Actually, joined table t is used to limit sys.foreign_key_columns table output. It may be superflous, but it depends on your schema.

Answer (score 144):

Another way is to check the results of

```
sp_help 'TableName'
```

(or just highlight the quoted TableName and press ALT+F1)

With time passing, I just decided to refine my answer. Below is a screenshot of the results that `sp_help` provides. A have used the AdventureWorksDW2012 DB for this example. There is numerous good information there, and what we are looking for is at the very end - highlighted in green:

[image]

Comment: +1 This gives a lot of helpful information and this shows foreign keys at the bottom of the output

Comment: This gives me a lot of info in the smallest number of lines of code

Comment: This is the coolest short-cut! Completely beats Ctl-R to refresh the schema!

Comment: Refresh Local InteliSense Cache = Ctrl+Shift+R; 
Ctrl+R = show/hide results pane
(or at least these are my defaults for SSMS2008 and SSMS2014)

Comment: myfriend told me to block the tablename and press alt + F1 but that shortcut not works on me. this command help me!! thankss

Answer (score 58):

Try this

```
SELECT
  object_name(parent_object_id) ParentTableName,
  object_name(referenced_object_id) RefTableName,
  name 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id('Tablename')
```

Comment: Short and elegant, plus works for me! Only thing is the `name` value returned is an internal name (methinks), and not the actual column name in the parent table. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What I see here that the `ParentTableName` would always be same as the given '`Tablename`' in the where clause (if included). This may be intentional, and will be more useful when queried for **more than one** table.

Answer (score 40):

I found this answer quite simple and did the trick for what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956348/652519

A summary from the link, use this query:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

Quick and simple. I was able to locate all the foreign key tables, respective columns and foreign key names of 15 tables pretty quickly.

As @mdisibio noted below, here's a link to the documentation that details the different parameters that can be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fkeys-transact-sql

Comment: There are five other parameters to filter on, the most useful of which to know is the second where you can specify a non-default schema, e.g. `EXEC sp_fkeys 'Payroll', 'accounting'`

Comment: This one helped, thx!

Comment: @SushiDynamite Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the best way  to find out Foreign Key Relationship in all Database.

```
exec sp_helpconstraint 'Table Name'
```

and one more way

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME='Table Name'
--and left(CONSTRAINT_NAME,2)='FK'(If you want single key)
```

Comment: This solution `exec sp_helpconstraint 'Table Name'` is the only one that returns any rows at all for me. However the contraint name is gibberish.
`PRIMARY KEY (clustered) PK__org_soft__3213E83FE6B07364`

Comment: This does only work if you have enough rights to access the table Information Schema

Answer (score 15):

I am using this script to find all details related to foreign key. 
I am using INFORMATION.SCHEMA. 
Below is a SQL Script:

```
SELECT 
    ccu.table_name AS SourceTable
    ,ccu.constraint_name AS SourceConstraint
    ,ccu.column_name AS SourceColumn
    ,kcu.table_name AS TargetTable
    ,kcu.column_name AS TargetColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
        ON ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu 
        ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME  
ORDER BY ccu.table_name
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to see the columns that are foreign keys and the related tables that the column references, and this sums it up nicely. Thanks!

Comment: This was missing some foreign keys on some of my tables while [@LittleSweetSeas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17501870/3312114) showed them

Answer (score 7):

if you want to go via SSMS on the object explorer window, right click on the object you want to drop, do view dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT 
    obj.name      AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name      AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name     AS [table],
    col1.name     AS [column],
    tab2.name     AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name     AS [referenced_column]
FROM 
     sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id 
        AND col2.object_id =  tab2.object_id;
```

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can just right click the table in the 
object explorer  and select "View Dependencies".   This would give a you a
good starting point.  It shows tables, views, and procedures that reference
the table.

Answer (score 3):

In Object Explorer, expand the table, and expand the Keys:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key` for a table is:

```
/*  Get primary key and foreign key for a table */
USE DatabaseName;

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%' AND
TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'FK%' AND
TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 1):

--The following may give you more of what you're looking for:

```
create Procedure spShowRelationShips 
( 
    @Table varchar(250) = null,
    @RelatedTable varchar(250) = null
)
as
begin
    if @Table is null and @RelatedTable is null
        select  object_name(k.constraint_object_id) ForeginKeyName, 
                object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) TableName, 
                object_name(k.referenced_object_id) RelatedTable, 
                c.Name RelatedColumnName,  
                object_name(rc.object_id) + '.' + rc.name RelatedKeyField
        from sys.foreign_key_columns k
        left join sys.columns c on object_name(c.object_id) = object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) and c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
        left join sys.columns rc on object_name(rc.object_id) = object_name(k.referenced_object_id) and rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id
        order by 2,3

    if @Table is not null and @RelatedTable is null
        select  object_name(k.constraint_object_id) ForeginKeyName, 
                object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) TableName, 
                object_name(k.referenced_object_id) RelatedTable, 
                c.Name RelatedColumnName,  
                object_name(rc.object_id) + '.' + rc.name RelatedKeyField
        from sys.foreign_key_columns k
        left join sys.columns c on object_name(c.object_id) = object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) and c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
        left join sys.columns rc on object_name(rc.object_id) = object_name(k.referenced_object_id) and rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id
        where object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) =@Table
        order by 2,3

    if @Table is null and @RelatedTable is not null
        select  object_name(k.constraint_object_id) ForeginKeyName, 
                object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) TableName, 
                object_name(k.referenced_object_id) RelatedTable, 
                c.Name RelatedColumnName,  
                object_name(rc.object_id) + '.' + rc.name RelatedKeyField
        from sys.foreign_key_columns k
        left join sys.columns c on object_name(c.object_id) = object_name(k.Parent_Object_id) and c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
        left join sys.columns rc on object_name(rc.object_id) = object_name(k.referenced_object_id) and rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id
        where object_name(k.referenced_object_id) =@RelatedTable
        order by 2,3



end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query to display `Foreign key` constaraints:

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
---- optional:
ORDER BY
1,2,3,4
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME='YourTable'
```

Taken from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/

Answer (score 1):

You can also return all the information about the `Foreign Keys` by adapating @LittleSweetSeas answer:

```
SELECT 
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) ConsTable,
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) refTable,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
order by
ConsTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure

```
_sp_help 'tbl_name'_
```

does give a lot of information but I find the procedures

```
_sp_fkeys 'tbl_name'_ and 
_sp_pkeys 'tbl_name'_
```

easier to use, and maybe with a more future-proof result.

(And they do answer the OP perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

try the following query.

```
select object_name(sfc.constraint_object_id) AS constraint_name,
       OBJECT_Name(parent_object_id) AS table_name ,
       ac1.name as table_column_name,
       OBJECT_name(referenced_object_id) as reference_table_name,      
       ac2.name as reference_column_name
from  sys.foreign_key_columns sfc
join sys.all_columns ac1 on (ac1.object_id=sfc.parent_object_id and ac1.column_id=sfc.parent_column_id)
join sys.all_columns ac2 on (ac2.object_id=sfc.referenced_object_id and ac2.column_id=sfc.referenced_column_id) 
where sfc.parent_object_id=OBJECT_ID(<main table name>);
```

this will give the constraint_name, column_names which will be referring and tables which will be depending on the constraint will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Littlesweetsea had what I needed, but often it's good to know the schema.

```
SELECT schema_NAME(f.schema_id) schemaname,
   OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
   COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
FROM 
   sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN 
   sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
   sys.tables t 
      ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
WHERE 
   OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'soldiers'
```