# Deleting records from 500 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been given project with over 500 tables with undocumented foreign key assignments. The main table is tblCompanies of which, I need to delete companies and all the related data in the other connected tables. Does anyone know of a tool or a method I could use to either accomplish or hunt down the order of deletion from these tables?

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: It will vary a lot depending on what DBMS you're using. Please update your question to let us know what it is.

Comment: Google terms for such undertakings include "SQL Data Modeler" and "Reverse Engineering". Tools like GraphViz could help to visualize the relations.

Comment: Try the SQL query given in answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/483193/17776