# Different behavior in 2 SQL servers

Tags: sql-server

I have a project that run some integration tests. The project creates a new database each time and run the tests against this new db. Recently I moved this project to a new server and I'm having some issues when delete data from the db.

I execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1;
DELETE FROM TABLE2;
DELETE FROM TABLE3;
```

On the server A everything works as expected, however using server B I'm getting the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_....". The conflict occurred in database
>   "TestDB", table "Table1", column
>   '...'.

Both servers have the same version of SQL server

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3401.0 (X64) 
    Jan  9 2014 13:22:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

**Both Schema and data are the same and DB are created using the same process.**

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your schemas are different between the 2 servers.

Comment: They are not the same.  One has foreign keys, and one doesn't.

Comment: @Joe Possibly they are different, but not necessarily. Please see my answer for details :).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is possible to have the same schema in both places, and even the same data, and experience different behavior. How? Because constraints (CHECK and FOREIGN KEY) can be disabled. Yup.

To see if the Foreign Key in question is enabled or disabled, just run the the following, making sure to put the name of the FK in question in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE [name] = N'{name_of_FK_in_question}';
```

Look at the column named `is_disabled`. I suspect that it is set to `1` on Server A (where everything "works") and is `0` on Server B (where things "don't work").  I put "works" and "don't work" in quotes, because if this is truly the case, then reality is the opposite of what you are experiencing. Meaning, the system with the FK enabled and getting the error is actually working as that is what FKs should do. The system not getting an error is possibly allowing orphaned (i.e. bad) data in.

To enable the FK, run the following:

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name}
   WITH CHECK -- verifies the data currently in the table
   CHECK CONSTRAINT [{name_of_FK_in_question}];
```

Of course, if the bad data is there, you either need to:

- Delete the bad data first, or
- Specify `WITH NOCHECK` on the `ALTER` so that it will accept the bad data:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE {table_name}
     WITH NOCHECK -- accept the bad data aleady there
     CHECK CONSTRAINT [{name_of_FK_in_question}];
  ```

  However, this does not solve the issue 100%. If you run that SELECT query (noted above) again, you should see that the `is_disabled` field is now set to `0`. BUT, if you look at the `is_not_trusted` field, it will be set to `1`. If a constraint is enabled yet not trusted, it will enforce its rule as expected, but the Query Optimizer (Q.O.) will ignore it, which is generally not a great thing as the constraints are actually used not just to enforce data integrity rules, but also as clues for the Q.O. to logically reduce certain steps in some queries (i.e. they sometimes help increase performance). In order to get the constraint to be "trusted", you will have to delete the bad data and verify all constraints on the table via:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE {table_name}
     WITH CHECK -- verifies the data currently in the table
     CHECK CONSTRAINT [{name_of_FK_in_question}];
  ```

  However, if for some reason you *need* the "bad" data, then you will just have a Foreign Key that enforces data integrity but has no potential for improving performance (which is still *much* better than having no FK defined :).

For more info, please see the MSDN page for [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

---

For the sake of completeness I will also mention that it is possible that on Server A (where there is no error), that the FK is defined with the option `ON DELETE CASCADE` which auto-deletes and related data prior to removing the row(s) from the table that is being deleted from, while Server B (where there is an error) does not have the `ON DELETE` action specfied (or is specified as `NO ACTION`). This, however, is something that *should* show up when doing a schema compare (unless specifying to ignore the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` actions), whereas whether the constraint is enabled or disabled is more likely to be ignored in a schema compare.

Answer (score 2):

There is a foreign key (named in the error message) which is preventing you from deleting an item from `Table1` because it would violate the foreign key (i.e. a there would be a row in the other table which referenced the row that you were about to delete)

The difference between the two databases is going to either be:

- The first database didn't have the foreign key
- The first database didn't have any rows in the table constrained by the foreign key

To find which table the foreign key is on see the question [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

> ```
> EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
> ```

Comment: DB is created with the same process and I have compared the schema and both are the same.

Comment: @estebane97 Then the data must be different

Comment: @estebane97 and Justin: it is possible to have the same schema, and even insert the same data, yet only see the FK violation in one place. I explain the difference in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894403/577765).

Answer (score 0):

Like Justin says, either the keys or data isn't the same, if it works for your case, then setting the keys to cascade of delete will remedy this, but you must identify the keys first.