# Script to output information of foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know the detail about  my foreign keys.

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys;
```

But I need more than the information I can get now. 
Is there a way to know the columns they are refering to by using scripts like this ?

Answer (score 1):

To get list of all tables and their column names, use the next code:-

```
select 
    t.name as TableWithForeignKey, 
    c.name as ForeignKeyColumn 
from 
    sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
inner join 
    sys.tables as t on fk.parent_object_id = t.object_id
inner join 
    sys.columns as c on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
where 
    fk.referenced_object_id in (select object_id 
                               from sys.tables )
order by 
    TableWithForeignKey
```

Reference:- [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks, it's so complex, I don't understand anything in your script t all. But I see `foreign_key_columns` seems like the one I'm looking for.