# Is there a query to see all the references in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server

I want a simple way to find all the Foreign Keys of my table.

For example having a table Customers, I want to find the tables with a relationship to this table, I use to find relationships using the Diagram but it is too slow.

```
Desired result = Customers_Accounts, Customers_Cities, Customers_Properites, etc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just **select your table** and press **ALT + F1**, at the bottom of the result set you will see all the references

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that ALT F1 executes sp_help ‘object_name’, where object_name is the highlighted table. Keyboard shortcuts can easily be changed by users or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the dependencies is slow is due to the number and complexity of queries that sql sever runs in order to show you a nice hierarchical structure.

There are some ways to get the data you need which vary depending on the version of sql and how much info you are looking for.

Taken from [Microsoft Docs - View the Dependencies of a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Production.vProductAndDescription');   
GO
```

Obviously you'll need to change the `AdventureWorks2012` to your database and `Production.vProductAndDescription` to your Customer schema and table name.

The above works for the latest sql server editions, for older editions you may need to refer to the following links:

[MSSQL Tips - Different Ways to Find SQL Server Object Dependencies](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/)

[MSSQL Tips - Listing SQL Server Object Dependencies](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1294/listing-sql-server-object-dependencies/)

Comment: running this I always get 0 rows and I am sure my table has FKs **SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Participation');**

Comment: @Kevin what version of sql server are you using?