# Finding join path from one table to another

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, algorithm, select

EDIT: Is there a way or any methods/algorithms to find path of joins from one table to another?

[image: Database tables example]

Example:

I want to select first_name from person, name from country where country is Slovakia. User will only choose fields that he wants to select and I need some kind of algorithm that will find out that I need to join from person to city to country.

Comment: This is basic SQL as far as I can see. Yes join all 3 of the tables. With the `join` ... `on` ... syntax it is pretty simple (instead of cross joining with comma and filtering in the where clause, although it would work too).

Comment: But, I want to create this programmatically. Yes it is pretty easy to do it yourself, but I want it to be universal and dynamic for any tables.

Comment: Why? Databases are optimized for those kind of queries. Can't you just dynamically replace the table and column names? Or is the real question which tables have to be joined? Something like a breadth first search over the foreign keys?

Comment: Which tables have to be joined, thats the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server this looks useful, but it will only work if all foreign keys are there, you can also omit them and queries still work the same... which happens way too often in practice.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know a way how to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
Select first_name from person p, city c, country cn where p.city_id = c.city_id and c.country_id = cn.country_id and cn.name = 'Slovakia'
```