# SQL-SERVER- get way relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server

i have a big DB, and i wants to create query that i give her two name of tables and she give me the relationships between her.

**for example:** 
in my DB i have three table:Person,SupportActitvity and ProcessesSupportActivity.
Person related to SupportActitvity , and SupportActitvity  related to ProcessesSupportActivity
if i want to get the ProcessesSupportActivity for Person i write:

```
select * 
from person 
join SupportActivity on Person.PersonId=SupportActivity.PersonId 
join ProcessSupportActivity on ProcessSupportActivity.SupportActivityId=SupportActivity.SupportActivityId
```

I want that when i write that for Person and ProcessSupportActivity he give me the relationships.

he return:

1. Person            PersonId           SupportActivity         PersonId
2. SupportActivity  SupportActivityId  ProcessSupportActivity SupportActivityId

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: This should get you started... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you very much!!!I succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to look for the shorter way, I call  to dijkstra algorithm.
The graph is constructed from all tables in DB, Each table it's was a node in the graph.
and the path it's was all of the relation of table.
obviously that the graph build in signaltone אם economize runtime.
And when you want to discover a connection between two tables in the database you send the source table and destination table and get the path....
It works amazing