# Locating Primary Key in other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble finding how some tables are joined across databases due to system privileges/restrictions (but due to the virus admins are off).

Essentially, I'm trying to find what/where other tables a certain table's Primary Key is referenced (or being used as a Foreign Key).

Is there anyway to do this?

I've tried:

> Select table_name, column_name
>
> From information_schema.key_column_usage

But all I get is just a list of the table name and column name that I'm searching for...

Oh, btw, I'm using SSMS 18.0 (SQL).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select object_name(parent_object_id) referencing_table, 
       object_name(referenced_object_id) referenced_table
from sys.foreign_keys
```

Technically a foreign key can reference a key other than the Primary Key, so if you want to exclude foreign keys referencing alternate keys, it would be:

```
select object_name(k.parent_object_id) referencing_table, 
       object_name(k.referenced_object_id) referenced_table
from sys.foreign_keys k
join sys.indexes i
  on i.object_id = k.referenced_object_id
 and i.index_id = k.key_index_id
where i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: Think you for the quick answer! Excuse my stupidity here, but could you provide an example, please?