# SQL database view all foreign keys

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to view all foreign keys of my database and I have the following code to do that:

```
SELECT 
  tc.TABLE_NAME,
  sc.COLUMN_NAME,
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as sc
on sc.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
order by tc.TABLE_NAME
```

But it seems to give more results than it should be. It gives around 30.000 result and it should be no more than 2000. What I am doing wrong.
PS: I need this to return the table name, column name, column id and constraint type for further implementation in Laravel application.

Comment: check if this might might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'":

```
SELECT 
tc.TABLE_NAME,
sc.COLUMN_NAME,
CONSTRAINT_NAME,
CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as tc
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as sc
on sc.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
order by tc.TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: That's only one of the problems with the original query.  Because all columns of the table are joined, not only the FK columns.  Table sys.foreign_key_columns  should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here is to use `EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'`. Check this out for more details

[check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)