# Find all possible joins in one schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I find all possible joins in one schema? For example up to level 2, 3 and 4.

I can do something like this:

```
*;with combination as (
 select distinct rn = DENSE_RANK() over (order by table_name), table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
)
select
 combination_no = ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By NEWID()),
 c1.table_name, c2.table_name, c3.table_name, c4.TABLE_NAME
from combination c1, combination c2, combination c3, combination c4
where
 c1.rn < c2.rn and
 c2.rn < c3.rn and
 c3.rn < c4.rn
order by c1.rn, c2.rn, c3.rn, c4.rn
```

But, it's not what I meant. Can I generate these results only where there are connections?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Easy1908 . . . There are basically an infinite number of *possible* joins -- after all, the conditions on the `join` can have basically any functions applied to them.  Hence, your question is unclear.  Also what you mean by "level" is quite unclear.

Comment: Don't forget that a table can be related to itself, e.g. a parent/child relationship. How far down that rabbit hole do you want to keep joining?

Comment: The undocumented but super useful sp_msdependencies can be of assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to generate some output which shows the tables involved in foreign key relationships, and the columns included in those keys.

This information is stored in the `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns` DMVs.

See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Also, don't write joins using where syntax. Use ANSI 92 syntax. Ie, instead of:

```
select * from T1, T2 where T1.col = T2.col
```

Use

```
select * from T1 join T2 on T1.col = T2.col
```

Comment: The "where syntax" you mention is called ANSI-89,

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all responds.
I did something like this:

```
 SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS tab,
    col1.name AS col,
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
    into #temp
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
```

and after that I can use:

```
select 'Select  top 10 * from '+ tab+ ' join ' + referenced_table +' on ' + col + ' = ' + referenced_table+'.' +referenced_column
    from #temp
```

Thats gave me all possible joins with other tables, and thats what I wanted. Now I'm still thinking, how to receive all possible joins when I want 2 and 3 joins in my query(without self join).