# How to find all the relations between all tables with INFORMATION_SCHEMA in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get all relations between all db tables by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

I tried to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` to get it, because it works with MySQL, but it doesn't have `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` and `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` columns in SQL Server.

Comment: If you want more bespoke information, specific to the RDBMS, you are better off using the bespoke objects for the RDBMS. In SQL Server, that's the `sys` schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit more of those views to get what you need:

- List of FKs with both ends specified is in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`
- Mapping between referenced key and its table name is in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

Something like this should work:

```sql
select cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME as [ForeignKeyName],
    cu.TABLE_SCHEMA as [ReferencingTableSchema],
    cu.TABLE_NAME as [ReferencingTableName],
    cu.COLUMN_NAME as [ReferencingColumnName],
    tc.TABLE_SCHEMA as [ReferencedTableSchema],
    tc.TABLE_NAME as [ReferencedTableName],
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME as [ReferencedKeyName]
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc on rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
        and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
order by cu.TABLE_SCHEMA, cu.TABLE_NAME, cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, cu.COLUMN_NAME;
```

The query is probably not 100% fool-proof, you need to check with multi-column FKs, and possibly relationships between tables in different schemas. Still, a good starting point.

Oh, and if you need a column name from the parent table, you will need the `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` again, this time for the referenced table. Might be tricky with multi-column FKs, look at the `ORDINAL_POSITION` column, it should give you the correlation which child column references which parent one.