# Can you do a select on the results of a stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
select * from (EXEC sp_SomeStoredProc)
```

If you can't do this then what is stopping it from being added to the SQL standard or T-SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this, however you can do it as an insert. e.g.

```
insert mytable
exec myStoredProcedure
```

Also, never name your stored procedures sp_xxxx.  This is because SQL will always search in the system stored procedure area due to the sp_ before looking in the user stored procedures, leading to a small loss in performance that could add it to be fairly significant on a process that is run frequently.

Comment: Can you do this with the "select into" and then drop the table after?

Comment: I can't remember if you can do this with select into, but I don't think so.  You will need to create the full table structure beforehand

Comment: No but you can use a #temp table

Comment: If you use this with a temp table you will need to create it first and know the number of columns and types of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but certainly not the right way to go:

```
USE test
GO
CREATE procedure dbo.select1 AS
SELECT 1 
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='OQtest', @datasrc='localhost', @provider='SQLNCLI', @srvproduct=''
GO
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(OQtest, 'test.dbo.select1')
```

You may also need to adjust security settings on the server for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

What if the stored proc returns no rows? Multiple result sets? Changes?
The potential usages of a stored proc are many and varied.

When you have `SELECT * FROM TableOrView`, there is a direct binding and easily checked syntax and structure.

More correctly, in the relational sense, a stored proc is not a relation/table so you can't select from it.

User defined functions achieve what you want but allow the code to conform to some relation/table concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, but you could consider a function in sqlserver2005. Here's an example function that creates a table from a comma separated list

```
Create Function [dbo].[CsvToInt] ( @Array varchar(1000)) 
returns @IntTable table 
    (IntValue int)
AS
begin

    declare @separator char(1)
    set @separator = ','

    declare @separator_position int 
    declare @array_value varchar(1000) 

    set @array = @array + ','

    while patindex('%,%' , @array) <> 0 
    begin

      select @separator_position =  patindex('%,%' , @array)
      select @array_value = left(@array, @separator_position - 1)

        Insert @IntTable
        Values (Cast(@array_value as int))

      select @array = stuff(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')
    end

    return
end
```

And then simple select from the function...

```
Select * FROM dbo.CsvToInt('1,2,3,5')
```

And you'll get a table value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach described by ck but this is not really recommended.
You can check the [INSERT-EXEC](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) section of a great post [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) by [Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/) for more details.