# Is it possible to call stored procedure in view?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

A similar question about sql-server has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view). I'm wondering if its possible in MySql.

**edit:**

I want to use result set returned from procedure in view.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql) may help. In short, yes, you can achieve that with a function used in the view definition body.

Comment: @dawebber: I had seen this thread earlier but I'm not sure if it is related. It seems it tells how to call stored function with parameter in view. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: are you specifically wanting to call an SP? I did mention the word function on my answer, since I didn't want to assume that you were specifically wanting to call an SP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get result-set and use routine in FROM clause - NO. Stored routines (procedures or functions) in MySQL cannot return tables as result value.

But you can use functions as simple values, for example -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION mul10(Param1 INT)
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
  RETURN Param1 * 10;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1
AS
SELECT mul10(2) AS column1;

SELECT column1 FROM view1;
----------
20
```

Comment: I think your first sentence answers my question. I wanted to use result set from procedure in view. I edited the question as well. Thanks.