# Call a stored procedure from within a view

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I have a procedure that creates a table, is it possible to have a view (or similar) that can call the procedure then select from the table?

I've tried this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `new_routine`(p1 INT) RETURNS int(1)
BEGIN
    CALL rMergeDateFields();
    RETURN 1;
END


CREATE VIEW `db`.`vIntervals` AS
  SELECT new_routine(0) AS col1;
  SELECT * FROM MergedData;
```

but I get this error

> Error 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. Views are *typically* read-only operations; and that behavior cannot be guaranteed if stored-procedures are invoked.

Related question:

[How to call Stored Procedure in a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view)

[Is it possible to call stored procedure in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799489/is-it-possible-to-call-stored-procedure-in-view)

Here is a canonical resource:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.

As invoking the stored procedure cannot assure 1:1 relationships with view rows, the update is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from a view, but a stored procedure itself can return a result set.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `merge_and_select` ()
BEGIN
    CALL rMergeDateFields();
    SELECT * FROM MergeData;
END $$
```

If you CALL merge_and_select() the rMergeDateFields procedure will be run and then you will get the contents of the MergeData table returned to you, in one step... which sounds like what you're wanting.

This is, however, a really bad implementation, because there's no control for concurrent calls to merge_and_select(), so all kinds of things could go wrong if it's run more than once at the same time.

However, depending on what you *really* need rMergeDateFields() to do, it's possible that you could rewrite rMergeDateFields() to actually perform whatever work you need done and return it directly to the client without using the MergeData table using an unbounded SELECT, as shown above.

Anything you SELECT in a stored procedure without using `INTO` a variable is returned to the client as a response from the `CALL`.