# How to call SPs with #temp using OpenRowSet in a View?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, view, temp, openrowset

I am trying to run a stored procedure from an application which supports connecting to only tables and views. My work around was to use a view which gets results from SP via Openrowset(). Turns out that the SP is using #temp tables to store intermediate results and this is a DDL operation which seems to be not supported for distributed queries. I can replace #temp with @temp table variables but it slowing down the whole code drastically (I was using bulk insert (select * into #temp from t1) to speed up things).

The error message I am getting is

> Cannot process the object "exec
>   DW.dbo.TestSpWithTempTable".
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" indicates
>   that either the object has no columns or the current user does not
>   have permissions on that object.

**Is there anyway I can use #temp tables in an SP and call it from a view using OpenRowSet?**

```
CREATE PROC TestSpWithTempTable
AS
Select distinct TxnType into #txnTypes from Transactions
-- lot of other stuffs going on here
select TxnType from #temp
GO
```

The view I created is:

```
CREATE VIEW SelectDataFromSP
    SELECT a.*
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',
         'exec DW.dbo.TestSpWithTempTable') AS a
```

The code that works but slow is

```
CREATE PROC TestSpWithTempTable
AS
declare @TxnTypes table(TxnType varchar(100))    
insert into @TxnTypes
Select distinct TxnType from Transactions
-- lot of other stuffs going on here
select TxnType from @TxnTypes
GO
```

Comment: can you access the user defined functions in that sql server instance?if yes then refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view

Comment: Yes, I can access the views..

Comment: I am asking about access to user defined functions, not to views.

Comment: Apologies.. I meant views, functions and all other objects. I checked the links too but didn't find them helpful. The issue here is that SQL server doesn't like DML in remote procedure calls. I am looking for a work around on that..

Comment: Instead of trying to make it work with temp tables you could try to optimize the stored procedure to completely remove them.

Comment: I am not trying to find an alternate solution for my case but trying to investigate if this can be achieved keeping the #temp tables. The question here is the usage of DML in remote execution and how to get that done in SQL.. Thanks for your efforts Lieven but what I want to do is a bit different thing..