# Call stored procedure from view

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

There are multiple threads for this but none of them explain exactly that how we can call stored procedure from view.My basic requirement  is to show data from multiple dynamic tables  in view IN mysql.

```
user_date_1
user_date_2
user_date_3
user_date_n
```

Please explain .

Answer (score 0):

look at this thread: [How to call Stored Procedure in a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view)

You need to use a function that calls the stored procedure. After that you can call the function from within your query/view.

some extra info on the restrictions of views:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-restrictions.html

Comment: hi @ruben  i tried your links but i am not able to create function which call procedure. also i read somewhere that we cann't return table from function.