# How can I avoid failing an entire INSERT batch due to 1 NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a primary key and a stored procedure I use to insert to that table. I have no control over the stored procedure and cannot change it. Sometimes the procedure returns many records and 1 record with a NULL value for the primary key column. At the moment, the entire batch of new rows fails to insert.

How can I configure my code or the table to fail only on the 1 row with the NULL value, but allow the other rows to be inserted?

Here is some test code:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #tbl

    CREATE TABLE #tbl (
     col INT NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT PK_tbl PRIMARY KEY (col ASC)
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
     IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
    )

    SET XACT_ABORT OFF

    --Imagine this is the procedure that cannot be edited
    insert into #tbl (col) values 
    (null), (1), (2)

    --Ideally, the table would have 1 and 2
    select * from #tbl
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't the procedure be altered?

Comment: Have a read of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728898/can-you-do-a-select-on-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure-in-t-sql. Far from brill though...

Comment: What is the desired outcome if the value is null to ignore those rows or to default in a 'valid' value.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we're not really talking about a #temporary table, you could create an instead of insert trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.PreventNullsOnTableName
ON dbo.TableName
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.TableName SELECT col1 FROM inserted WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;
END
GO
```

You may also want to use `GROUP BY col1` to prevent PK violations, but that depends on whether you want to handle that gracefully or raise an error.

You could also remove the `NOT NULL` constraint and instead of having a `PRIMARY KEY`, create a unique filtered index `WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have NOT NULL on col INT.  It can still be PK but it will only allow one null.  Then you can delete the null row.

OK I was wrong the PK cannot be null.  But you can have a null unique non clustered index.  It is fundamentally a PK but not clustered.  If the insert has at most one null then the insert will succeed and you can then delete the 1 row that is null.

Comment: What if the set is `values (null), (1), (null), (2)`?

Comment: SQL Server does not seem to allow nullable primary keys at all.

Comment: My suggestion was for the fallback of a unique constraint (which does allow **one** NULL).

Comment: Sorry you are right.  I did test it by creating a table in SQL Management Studio and I had an nullable int as PK.  Table saved without an error so assumed it took.  But it did NOT save as nullable.

Comment: Did some more testing and null cannot be a PK but it can be unique non clustered.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the problem state said sometimes return 1 null.  So is it could do the insert then delete the null.

Comment: PK still doesn't make sense since it can't allow any `NULL`s (whether the potential to have 1 or more than one is the same).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You criticise my answer of using unique key rather than a PK as it will accept null and then you post it in your answer.  Thanks for help on my insert speed question.

Comment: @BalamBalam what are you talking about? I criticized the fact that you suggested a PK allows one null. Where in my answer do I say anything about allowing nulls in a PK column? Anyway I didn't down-vote you for it even though you were incorrect. What would you like me to do? Go back in time and read your correction before I commented on what your answer **USED** to say? People point out incorrect statements not to give you a hard time, but to prevent other users from inheriting perceptions based on those incorrect statements. We're all here to learn and help others learn, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7827/discussion-between-balambalam-and-aaron-bertrand)