# Is there a succinct way to retrieve a list of table column names with T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I'm looking round a SQL Server database I often want to interactively retrieve a simple list of column names for a database table (no data type information etc., just the names) using `sqlcmd`.

I can do this:

```
EXEC sp_columns @table_name = 'tablename'
```

which gives me much more than I want and wraps in a command prompt to the extent that it is close to unintelligible, or I can do this:

```
SELECT col.name 
FROM sysobjects obj 
INNER JOIN syscolumns col
ON obj.id = col.id where obj.name = 'tablename'
```

which gives me what I want but is a bit verbose.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM (EXEC sp_columns @table_name = 'tablename')
```

but that doesn't work (see, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)).

Is there a more succinct way to do this (i.e. one that is easier to type at the command line and therefore less error prone)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the ANSI-defined INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Try `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for starters and go on from there.

Your example would require this SQL:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

Comment: This has the advantage that it's an ANSI standard view, and will therefore not change when Microsoft change the underlying system tables.

Comment: @Christian: the new catalog views are also designed the same way

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
```

[Catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> We recommend that you use catalog
>   views because they are the most
>   general interface to the catalog
>   metadata and provide the most
>   efficient way to obtain, transform,
>   and present customized forms of this
>   information. All user-available
>   catalog metadata is exposed through
>   catalog views.

Purely personal, but I don't like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views

Comment: The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views were designed by a committee - that says it all :-( Huge, ugly, not very useful....

Comment: @marc_s: he he. Quite cynical,no?

Comment: I use information schema because I can remember how to write the query.  The sys and object_id things seem like they were designed by the same guy who did Frankenstein. :)