# openrowset to self

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openrowset

I have a stored procedure that returns around 1000 rows.
I want to `SELECT` from it.

Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
SELECT * FROM (EXEC my_proc)
```

That doesn't work so I have to use `openrowset`.

I'm not keen on doing this because it would just be connecting to itself.

Aside from creating a temp table, are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Select columns from result set of stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)