# Can I search stored procedure results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a stored procedure which returns a large set of data. Can I write another query to filter the result of stored procedure?

For example:

```
select * from
EXEC xp_readerrorlog
where LogDate = '2011-02-15'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select columns from result set of stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)

Comment: I always use google site:stackoverflow.com select+from+stored+procedure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would need to first insert the results of the stored procedure on a table, and then query those results.

```
create table #result (LogDate datetime, ProcessInfo varchar(20),Text text)

INSERT INTO #Result
EXEC xp_readerrorlog

SELECT *
FROM #Result
WHERE datepart(yy,LogDate) = '2012'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it part of a query, BUT you could insert the resulting data into a temp table or table variable and then use that for your query.

Answer (score 1):

Does returning the error log for just an entire day make the result any more useful? I think it will still be full of useless entries. If you're looking for specific events, why not use one of the filter parameters for xp_readerrorlog? The following wil return all rows in the current log that contain the string 'fail':

```
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'fail';
```

Comment: Right I posted just an example, I will be searching on other parameters. Your query can be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy output from sp to temporaty table.

```
insert into #temp
EXEC xp_readerrorlog
```

and then use where clause with the temp table

Answer (score 0):

or you can make a **Table-valued Function**