# Selecting columns from a MYSQL routine result

Tags: mysql

I have a routine called `sp_getalldata` and I want to select only 2 columns `col1` and `col2` from the resultset of the routine.

I've tried

SELECT col1, col2 FROM (CALL sp_getalldata())

but it is invalid. What are my options?

Comment: Similar question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use stored function as a data source in MySQL. The MySQL does not supports table functions. You only can write stored procedure with SELECT statement and call this procedure to output result-set.