# Determining which tables have GRANT SELECT to a specific custom role

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have been asked to get a list of all tables within our SQL Server 2008 database, which have SELECT permission to a specific role. It would need to be in a query, because then we need to write a script that revokes that GRANT SELECT permission.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an entire answer (and can't be - I don't have an SQL Server installation to fiddle with) but hopefully it will get you on the right track. It's executing a stored procedure.

```
USE yourDB;
GO
EXEC sp_table_privileges 
   @table_name = '%';
```

Within the results set, you'll be interested primarily in the third column, `table_name`, and the sixth column, `privileges`.

Source: [MSDN: sp_table_privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173835.aspx)

In my mind, the next step - assuming this is the data you are looking for - would be to wrap this SQL statement with one that inserts the results of the EXEC statement into a temporary table which you can then slice and dice as needed. This endeavour is left as an exercise to the reader (*nudge nudge*). The third answer on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure) may be of some use in extending the query given above but as always, YMMV.