# Get/Use the Select value from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to use a Stored Procedure - that I cannot change/modify. While it is a bit complicated, it can be simplified to be a `SELECT` statement i.e. with no `RETURN` or `OUTPUT` parameter. For the purpose of this discussion assume it to be something like:

```
SELECT [URL] as imgPath
     FROM [mydatasource].[dbo].[DigitalContent]
```

I need to execute this Stored Procedure passing in the Row ID (SKU) of each row in a Table.
I use a cursor for this as below:

```
DECLARE @sku varchar(100)
DECLARE @imgPath varchar(500)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT [SKU]
        FROM [mydatasource].[dbo].[PROD_TABLE]

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sku

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC @imgPath = [mydatasource].[dbo].[getImage] @sku
    --UPDATE PROD_TABLE SET ImgPath=@imgPath WHERE SKU=@sku
    SELECT @imgPath AS ImgPath
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sku
END
  CLOSE c
  DEALLOCATE c
```

Unfortunately, the return value `@imgPath` comes back as `0` i.e. success. This results in `0`s being inserted into my `PROD_TABLE` or dumped on the Console. However, as the `getImage` Stored Procedure executes, it dumps the correct values of `imgPath` to the console.

How do I get this correct value *(i.e. the result of the `SELECT` in the Stored Procedure)* in the Loop above, so that I can correctly update my `PROD_TABLE`?

### **Answer**

Thanks to **RBarryYoung** suggestion, my final code looks like:

```
DECLARE @sku varchar(100)
DECLARE @imgPath varchar(500)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT [SKU]
FROM [mydatasource].[dbo].[PROD_TABLE]
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sku

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #OutData ( imgPath varchar(500) )
    INSERT INTO #OutData EXEC [mydatasource].[dbo].[getImage] @sku
    --UPDATE PROD_TABLE SET ImgPath=(SELECT * FROM #OutData) WHERE SKU=@sku
    SELECT * FROM #OutData
    DROP TABLE #OutData

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @sku
END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c
```

The performance may not be the best, but at least it works :-).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Comment: Thank you **mr.Reband** again! I don't like to have to populate a Table Variable for this - but it seems like the only option :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a temp table (`#OutData`) whose definition matches the output dataset being returned by `getImage`.

Then, change your `EXEC ..` statement to this:

```
INSERT INTO #OutData  EXEC [mydatasource].[dbo].[getImage] @sku
```

---

Response to the question: "*Is it possible to insert the Key/Row ID into the Temp Table, that way I will not have to TRUNCATE it after each loop iteration?*"

First, as a general rule you shouldn't use `TRUNCATE` on #temp tables as there are some obscure locking problems with that.  If you need to do that, just `DROP` and `CREATE` them again (they're optimized for that anyway).

Secondly, you cannot modify the dataset returned by a stored procedure in any way.  Of course once its in the #temp table you can do what you want with it.  So you could add a KeyId column to `#OutData`.  Then inside the loop make a second #temp table (`#TmpData`), and use `INSERT..EXEC` to dump into that table instead.  Then `INSERT..SELECT` into `#OutData` by selecting from `#TmpData`, adding your KeyID column.  Finally, `DROP TABLE #TmpData` as the last statement in your loop.

This should perform fairly well.

Comment: Thank you **RBarryYoung**. I hate to be populating a Table Variable every time I run through the loop.

Comment: My Stored Procedure returns only `imgPath` i.e. no Key, and I cannot modify it. Is it possible to insert the Key/Row ID into the Temp Table, that way I will not have to `TRUNCATE` it after each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you **RBarryYoung**. That worked for me. I used only one Temp Table, created and deleted in the loop to store the result of the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes executing code entirely inside SQL Server can be more difficult than doing so directly client-side, sending multiple queries calling the SProc (ideally batched in a single round-trip) and processing the results there directly.

Otherwise, the INSERT-EXEC method seems the easier if you absolutely can't modify the called procedure. There are a few alternative methods, all with some additional problems, shown here: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html