# Create table from nth result set of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns 4 result sets. The results sets have lots of columns.

What's the best way to create a table out of each result set? The data types and schema in the tables should be the same as the ones from the result sets.

I know I can do this to create a table from a selection:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME 
  AS SELECT * FROM USERS
```

So is there a way to select a result set from a stored procedure execution??

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question (which is why I'm commenting) but this is something I bookmarked a long while back that [might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)

Comment: Can you not do a `select into`?  if you just get table objects back from the sproc you could probably do a `select * into newtable from @returnedsproctable`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know next to no t-sql. I'm not sure how to select a single result set from a sproc.

Comment: how are they consumed currently?

Comment: It's a long story. Short answer is, I'm not sure. They're consumed by a foxpro report in some way. I should mention that the four tables I wish to create from result sets don't yet exist.

Comment: The `into` would create the table.  If they existed already you'd need to do an insert.

Comment: How do I get @returnedsproctable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62690/discussion-between-sava-b-and-paqogomez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this was mostly covered in chat, it should still have an answer for others who might be wondering the same thing.

The only way to access a specific result set out of multiple results sets, and within the context of T-SQL, is via SQLCLR. Using C#, VB.Net, or any .Net language, you would use a `SqlDataReader` which can access the result sets separately.

The SQLCLR proc would simply exec the existing T-SQL proc and can either spit out a single result set (assuming an input param would specify which one to return as a result set) *or* could do a separate connection and directly call INSERT statements to do all 4 at the same time (although at that point it could just as well be a Console App or Windows Form or whatever).