# mysql calling stored procedure for where id in

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored proc that returns one column of id's for linking.

```
sql = call myproc(555)
```

The above works perfectly returning a result set of id's.

```
sql = "select * from mytable  where id in (call myproc(555))"
```

The above query says my syntax is incorrect and bombs.

Suggestions?
Thanks Glenn

Comment: I don't know really whether this is allowed or not, but if you use a user defined function instead of a stored procedure , it will work 100%

Comment: If I remember correctly, stored procs can't be used inside other queries (or at least are generally useless within them); go with @AbdoAdel suggestions and make it a `stored function` instead.

Comment: I found some hack to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure

Comment: Thanks for the very fast responses!   It helped knowing that stored procs can not be used inside another query.  I checked into functions, however it appears they can not return result sets.  What works perfectly is creating a  view.  Thanks again.