# insert only certain columns of a stored procedure into a temptable in one step

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a storedprocedure which has multiple columns. I want to insert only certain columns of this stored procedure into a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
Product VARCHAR(MAX),

)


INSERT INTO #Temp (Product)
EXEC mpaGetProducts
```

Currently I get the error :
"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

I do not want to insert into one table first and then select only required columns because there is a large amount of data and this would cause a hit on the performance.

I saw this post & a few others online but it wasn't very helpful :
[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35594430/1258492

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select columns from result set of stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.  There is no way to specify the columns you want to select directly from a stored procedure.

EDIT:  Actually, a slightly hacky way to do this is with `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT {Columns that I want}
FROM OPENQUERY(MyServer, 'EXEC MyStoredProc @Params');
```

Comment: oh yeah ? I was wondering the same since I couldn't come across anything online regarding my requirement

Comment: See my edit for the closest work-around I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide SP Description

If you run your SP the output might have several columns resulting in SELECT STATEMENT so try to mention what column you need to insert into table