# Using a variable in insert command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to use a variable in my INSERT command. This variable includes result value from a storedprocedure:

```
 declare @File as varbinary(max)
 exec @File=[dbo].[MySp]
```

[image]

but If I use `@File` in an INSERT command, another value of  is written in table

```
insert into  [dbo].[Plots] values ('test', @File)
```

[image]

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySp]
AS
BEGIN

EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'_RCODE_'
    , @input_data_1 = N'_INPUT_QUERY_'
    ,@output_data_1=N'OutputDataset'
--- Edit this line to handle the output data frame.
    WITH RESULT SETS (([plot] VARBINARY(max)));
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure its not an `out` parameter in your stored proc? If that is the case your stored proc syntax is not correct.

Comment: What is the datatype for the out parameter?

Comment: it is VARBINARY(MAX)

Comment: @Igor I have updated my post with SP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using of Stored Procedure is wrong.
There is a recordset on first screenshot, but after execution `exec @File=[dbo].[MySp]` you don't have the recordset in variable `@File`.
You got

> @return_status

in `@File`

> @return_status Is an optional integer variable that stores the return
>   status of a module. This variable must be declared in the batch,
>   stored procedure, or function before it is used in an EXECUTE
>   statement.

The right query can be like this:

```
declare @File as varbinary(max)
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    plot    VARBINARY(MAX)
)

INSERT @Table
exec [dbo].[MySp]

SELECT @File = MAX(plot)
FROM @Table

insert into  [dbo].[Plots] values ('test', @File)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `EXEC` call is getting the result code of the SP, which is 0 for success, I suppose, in the absence of an explicit return statement.

See this answer for more details on how to capture actual data from your SP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963991/16777