# Can I select from a SqlDataSource generated from a stored procedure that returns a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have this datasource in ASP.NET webforms:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDB%>" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
     SelectCommand="PM.s_Proc">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ProfileParameter Name="Year" PropertyName="Year" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="2023" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I need is basically creating another datasource which is the equivalent of:

```
select column 
from $SqlDataSource1
```

Comment: Should it be strictly a SqlDataSource  or just the column data is required (e.g. in a datatable or list)?

Comment: I just need the column data in a datasource, the original data is stored in a stored procedure that returns a table

Comment: Then this might help: [Select columns from result set of stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure)

Comment: yeah but how do I do it on asp.net with a datasource?

Comment: If you have permission, create another stored procedure based on `PM.s_Proc` and add a parameter for column-name and use this as the `SelectCommand` of the new SqlDataSourc. Don't think it is possible totally in webform without using TSQL.

Comment: What is the actual question? You've set the SelectCommand of the SqlDataSource. You get data back. If you bind the SqlDataSource to a component e.g. a GridView you get access to the data i.e. to all the returned columns including the one you want. Why do you need another SqlDataSource?

Comment: I can not select from a stored procedure, what I want is `select distinct col from table` but I have a stored procedure that returns a table